# How can I identify all cell addresses in a formula using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to get all cell addresses in a formula of one cell?

What I want to do is to read the formula of each cells, identify all the cells it's referring to in the formula and return a text. It's different from FORMULATEXT because I want the string to be a combination of row headers (actual English explaining what the cell is) and operators (might be the wrong term since I want basically everything else -- formula, parenthesis, etc.)

Comment: See for example: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/